# Android studio media player not starting

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
class MusicPlayer(c: Context){
    var context: Context = c
    private var player: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.sth)

    fun start() {
        Log.d("Music", context.toString())
        player.setOnPreparedListener(OnPreparedListener {
            Log.i(
                "Music",
                "player: $player"
            )
        })
        player.isLooping = false
        player.setVolume(1F, 1F)
        Log.d("Music", "START")
        player.start()
        Log.d("Music", "AFTER START")
    }
}
```

I have simple class to control the starting of the music. The `start()` is called from another activity as:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private lateinit var player: MusicPlayer
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        player = MusicPlayer(this)

        player.start()
    }
}
```

the logging logs everything in the `start()` so I think `player.start()` is going through but there is no sound even though I have max the volume on Emulator. The .mp3 file is in `raw` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)) you used to set the volume on your `MediaPlayer` should be fine.

```java
public void setVolume (float leftVolume, float rightVolume)
```

> **Sets the volume on this player.** This API is recommended for balancing the output of audio streams within an application. Unless you are writing an application to control user settings, this API should be used in preference to AudioManager#setStreamVolume(int, int, int) which sets the volume of ALL streams of a particular type. Note that the passed volume values are raw scalars in range 0.0 to 1.0. UI controls should be scaled logarithmically.

So before trying the further suggestion below, you may have a look at the following:

1. Is your mp3 file **sth** playable?
2. Can you ensure the maximized volume of your emulator is for playing Media? Not for playing Ringtone or Alarm?
3. Is your emulator able to emit sound? Can you try another emulator? Or even find a real device and try?

---

If none of the above troubleshooting methods work, you may consider manipulating the **global volume** as follow:

```kotlin
fun start() {
    player.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
        Log.i("Music", "player: $player")
    })
    player.isLooping = true
    // Set global volume
    val audioManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    val maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, 0)
    // Also set your Media Player to use Music Stream
    player.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder().setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build())
    Log.d("Music", "START")
    player.start()
    Log.d("Music", "AFTER START")
}
```

And as you are modifying the Audio setting in your App, make sure you have added the corresponding permission in your Manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Thannks!!!  The problem is exactly as you said, the emulator can't emit sound. So i did a cold boot and it worked :)